# What is TCPMon and How to install it on linux?

Tags: apache, tcpmon

I want to know about the TCPMon and how to install it on linux based distribution. Also what are the uses of the tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCPMon is a utility that allows the user to monitor the messages passed along in TCP based conversation. It is based on a swing UI and works on almost all platforms that Java supports.It has originally being part of Axis1 and now stands as an independent project.

Download and Install on Linux:

1.Download the zip package from [Apache TCPMon release](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/download.cgi)

2.Go to you download directory and copy the zip file to your preferred destination

3.Open terminal and navigate to the folder where you downloaded the zip file

4.Type in the terminal "unzip tcpmon-1.0-bin.zip" and unzip it

5. type "cd tcpmon-1.0-bin/build" and hit enter
6. type "chmod 777 tcpmon.sh" and hit enter

7.finally type ./tcpmon.sh

That's it

Comment: I believe the above link is no longer valid ... I found it here ... http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/tcpmon/1.0/